# Understanding of Theorem in Construction of Numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

*Theorem*. For every $x\in\mathbb{N}$\ {$0$} there is a $y$ such that $S(y)=x$. For every $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$, if $S(x)=S(y)$ then $x=y$.

I think, first sentence means that for every natural numbers (nonzero) has a successor.Yet, I couldn't understand what second sentence mean.

Comment: No, the first sentence says that every number other than zero is the successor of a number, not that every number has a successor. The second sentence means that if the success of x equals the successor of y, then x equals y.

Answer (score 1):

The second statement says that no pair of nonequal natural numbers have the same successor. If this axiom wasn't in place then the numbers could form a loop.

$ 0 \to 1 \to 1 \to \dots $